# I am getting wrong value from input for link (not form)

Tags: javascript, php, jsp

I am trying to get input from user and invoke Servlet with that parameter but I can not get changed value. I am getting initial value.

```
<% int quantity = 1; %>
<input type="text" name="quantity" style="width: 20px;left: 52px;" value="<%= quantity %>" class="form"/>
<a href="addToCart.jsp?id=<%= product_id %>&quantity= <%= quantity %>" id="greenBtn">Add to cart</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that JSP is a HTML **preprocessor**, meaning it would process the webpage before it's sent to users' browsers. On the user agent it would just be a simple HTML page, these markups (e.g. `<%= quantity %>`) are replaced with the value of the variable `quantity` when the page is generated. To achieve what you're aiming for, use javascript.

Comment: yes i did with javascript functions by calling that function on button.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function getlink(product_id) {
        var link = "addToCart.jsp?id="+product_id+"&quantity="+document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        window.location.replace(link);
    }
```

call this function

```
<a  href="javascript:getlink(<%=product_id%>);" id="greenBtn">Add to cart</a>
```